# Orientação a Objetos em PHP, exemplo crud com ajax

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, crud

Estou tentando aprender PHP Orientado a Objetos, porém estou com dificuldade em encontrar um exemplo. Alguém pode mostrar um exemplo simples do caso de crud abaixo:

- Uma classe em php, por exemplo usuário, nesta classe tem os métodos que, retornam o usuário pelo id.
- retornam todos os usuários.
- insere o usuário.
- atualiza o usuário.
- deleta o usuário.

Também queria saber como posso chamar este métodos.

No caso irei utilizar ajax então terei que utilizar um arquivo php instanciado o objeto da classe.

Peço desculpas pela ingenuidade, mas acredito que aqui terei os melhores exemplos e apoio nas dúvidas.

Se alguém souber/tiver algum material relevante a isso também agradeço.

Oque eu fiz:

```
  <?php
    class Listas{
      public $guid;
      public $eguid;
      public $concluida;
      public $titulo;
      public $descricao;
      public $datecreate;

      function listarListas($db){
        $result = $db->select('cad_listaconf');
        $res = array();
        $res = $db->getResult();

        return $res;
      }

      function inserirLista($eguid, $titulo, $descricao, $datecreate, $db){
        if ($query = $db->insert('cad_listaconf', array('eguid'=>$eguid,         'titulo'=>$titulo, 'descricao'=>$descricao, 'datacreate'=>$datecreate))){
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }

    }

?>
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: oque eu fiz ate agora criei uma classe, define as propriedades e criei um metodo que traz todos os registros utilizando uma outra classe de crud a essa classe e estou tentando chamar este método.

a minha dúvida e na questa dos parametros, por exemplo vou criar um metodo insertusuario com seus parametros, nao sei como fazer

Comment: Coloca essa parte que você fez na pergunta.

Comment: certo, vou postar oque fiz, funciona mas nao sei se é correto dessa forma

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: [PHP CRUD Operations without Page Refresh using jQuery Ajax MySQL](http://www.codexworld.com/php-crud-operations-jquery-ajax-mysql/)